# Represent JSON Array into String

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to make a JSON array into the String, but it is giving me error, like delete this token everytime. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

```
private String jString = "{
    \"geodata\": [
        {
                \"id\": \"1\",
                \"name\": \"Jenifer Hathway\",
                \"email\": \"jh@gmail.com\",
                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",
                \"gender\" : \"female\",
                \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\",
                \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\",
                \"phone\": {
                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",
                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",
                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"
                }
        },
        {
                \"id\": \"2\",
                \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\",
                \"email\": \"johnny_depp@gmail.com\",
                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",
                \"gender\" : \"male\",
                \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\",
                \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\",
                \"phone\": {
                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",
                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",
                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"
                }
        }

    ]
}";
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in this line: \"name\": Jenifer Hathway\", I think you want: \"name\": \"Jenifer Hathway\",

Comment: After making that changes, I have edited the question, still it is giving me delete token error. Something I am missing again..

Comment: Can you show me some example?

Comment: I've take your string, removed the escape character and pasted into this [http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/] JSON validator which returns back valid.  Maybe try posting the error verbatim

Comment: I'm guessing you have this String inside a class. but if you don't, it will give you that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't support multiline strings.

```
private String jString = "{"
+ "    \"geodata\": ["
+ "        {"
+ "                \"id\": \"1\","
+ "                \"name\": \"Jenifer Hathway\","
+ "                \"email\": \"jh@gmail.com\","
+ "                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\","
+ "                \"gender\" : \"female\","
+ "                \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\","
+ "                \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\","
+ "                \"phone\": {"
+ "                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\","
+ "                    \"home\": \"00 000000\","
+ "                    \"office\": \"00 000000\""
+ "                }"
+ "        },"
+ "        {"
+ "                \"id\": \"2\","
+ "                \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","
+ "                \"email\": \"johnny_depp@gmail.com\","
+ "                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\","
+ "                \"gender\" : \"male\","
+ "                \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\","
+ "                \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\","
+ "                \"phone\": {"
+ "                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\","
+ "                    \"home\": \"00 000000\","
+ "                    \"office\": \"00 000000\""
+ "                }"
+ "        }"
+ "    ]"
+ "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another typo on this line

```
\"home\": \"00 000000",
```

should be

```
\"home\": \"00 000000\",
```

I would also try escaping all the lines as suggested by others